# Sorting table rows by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, html-table

I am trying to sort alphabetically table. Similar to this example http://jsfiddle.net/q7VL3 but without using the plugin.

For example this table:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Destination</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class='country-name'>
        <td>Gernamy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='destination-name'>
        <td>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Hamburg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Berlin</td>
                    </tr>                           
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr class='country-name'>
        <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='destination-name'>
        <td>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rome</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sicily</td>
                    </tr>                           
            </div>
        </td>           
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I can sort the country names with the following code, the problem I have is how to sort it with the nested table:

```
        function sortCountriesByName(a, b) {
        if ($(a).find('td:first-Child').text() > $(b).find('td:first-Child').text()) {
            return 1;
        }

        if ($(a).find('td:first-Child').text() < $(b).find('td:first-Child').text()) {
            return -1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/eJf55/    this is a sample sorting have a look at this

Comment: can you share your real table? This table is messy I think